# Stuck on infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops

noob programmer here. Taking my first CS class in college and making first post on here so excuse me if the info i provide is not sufficient in advanced.

Still trying to figure out loops. Seem to get it but once there is loops within loops or if statements inside loops, I get thrown off and have no idea on how to proceed. For my assignment, I need the following to occur.

Would you like to process all the records in the file? (y/n) W
Please enter either y or n.
Would you like to process all the records in the file? (y/n) n
Enter number of records to process: two
XXXXXXXXXX Error-non numeric or negative value, try again
Enter number of records to process: 10

Here is my code:

```
char a = 0;             //User chooses Y or N
int ProcessAmount = 0;  //Amount of times to process if not all

  cout << "Would you like to process all the records in the file? (y/n) ";
  cin >> a;

  do{

    bool notDone = true;

      if(a  == 'n'){
        while(notDone){
              cout << "Enter records to process: ";
              cin >> ProcessAmount;

              if (cin.fail()){
                  cin.clear();
                  cin.ignore(40,'\n');
                  cout << "" << endl;
              }
              else{
                  notDone = false;  
              }
        }
      }else if(a != 'y' or a != 'n');
            cout <<"Please enter either y or n." << endl;

  }while( a != 'y');
```

Comment: I forgot to add! The loop occurs here: "Please enter either y or n."

Comment: How do you think `a` is going to be changed inside of that loop?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am just using a to declare users choice which is either y or n

Comment: But if input is neither 'y' or 'n' you must get new input.

Comment: So I need it to prompt the user to either enter y or n. That is if the user does not enter y or n. So I have the else if statement for (a != 'y' or a != 'n') is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to add `cin >> a` in there. BUT you have also semicolon after `if()` you should remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most problems are explained in comments, here is how I would fix it:

```cpp
char a = 0;             //User chooses Y or N
int ProcessAmount = 0;  //Amount of times to process if not all

cout << "Would you like to process all the records in the file? (y/n) ";
cin >> a;

while (a != 'y') {

  bool notDone = true;

  if(a  == 'n'){
    while(notDone){
      cout << "Enter records to process: ";
      cin >> ProcessAmount;

      if (cin.fail()){
          cin.clear();
          cin.ignore(40,'\n');
          cout << "" << endl;
      } else {
        notDone = false;
      }
    }
  } else if(a != 'y' or a != 'n') {
    cout <<"Please enter either y or n." << endl;
    cin >> a; // Need to get new input because old one is invalid.
  }

};
```

Also I don't see how `notDone` is used. Also I would strongly advise of using proper indentation, spaces around keywords as `while`, `for`, `if`, `else` as it is good style.

Comment: Still trying to figure out the proper indentation, just switched to VSCode due to the simplicity of the editor. Currently using vim that is integrated to my schools linux server, which makes it really confusing to use. Thank you!

Comment: your example did work, just to clarify, no need for a bool statement? would I be able to remove it? I added one assuming I would need a else statement to complete the if cin.fail statement

Comment: Most probably there is shortcut that formats the code (try `Ctrl+Shift+I`)

Answer (score 0):

You just put the y/n solicitation out of your loop then 'a' won't never change its value. Take a look of the change you may want:

```
do {
    cout << "Would you like to process all the records in the file? (y/n/f) ";  //f to break the loop
    cin >> a;

    bool notDone = true;

    if (a  == 'n') {
        //. . .
    } else if (a == 'y') {
        //You may want to do something when yes
    } else if (a != 'f')
              cout <<"Please enter either y/n or f." << endl;

} while( a != 'f')
```