# Stuck on a loop

Tags: c++, loops

I already [posted this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576144/stuck-on-infinite-loop), but none of the responses were correct once I implemented the suggestions I was given. Here is what I need to happen.

```
Would you like to process all the records in the file? (y/n) w
Error - Please enter either y or n.
Would you like to process all the records in the file? (y/n) n
Enter number of records to process: two
XXXXXXXXXX Error-non numeric or negative value, try again
Enter number of records to process: -10
XXXXXXXXXX Error-non numeric or negative value, try again
Enter number of records to process: 0
XXXXXXXXXX Error-non numeric or negative value, try again
Enter number of records to process: 10
Maximum requested record count of 10 reached
```

Here is what I have. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  char a = 0;            //User chooses Y or N
  int ProcessAmount = 0; //Amount of times to process if not all

  cout << "Would you like to process all the records in the file? "
       << "(y/n) ";
  cin >> a;

  if (a == 'y')
  {
    cout << "Processed all records successfuly" << endl;
  }

  do
  {

    if (a == 'n')
    {
      cout << "Enter number of records to process: ";
      cin >> ProcessAmount;

      if (ProcessAmount <= 0 or cin.fail())
      {
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "XXXXXXXXX Error-non numeric or negative value";
        cout << "" << endl;
        cin >> ProcessAmount;
      }
      else if (ProcessAmount >= 0 or (!(cin.fail())))
        ;
      {
        cout << "Maximum requested record count of " << ProcessAmount;
        cout << " reached" << endl;
        break;
      }
    }
    else
      (cin.fail());
    {
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(40, '\n');
      cout << "Please try again" << endl;
      cout << "Would you like to process all the records in the file? "
           << "(y/n) ";
      cin >> a;
    }

  } while (a == 'n');

}
```

Comment: Try to build state machine first for this on paper. The logic in the code is broken. E.g. how do you handle `y` in a loop?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure. Im still learning how loops work

Comment: Start from scratch. And by from scratch, I literally mean a blank project. Make your only goal. Your ONLY goal, to validate user input. The program should prompt the user for either y/n, and loop if they do not enter it. It sounds like it will take more time, but you will save time in the long run by tackling one functional point at a time.

Comment: Great suggest John thank you, leaving the rest of the code out helped focus on the error.

Comment: 10 hours isn't a very long time

Comment: If none of the answers to your first copy of this question were valid, why did you accept one of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck on infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576144/stuck-on-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `or` is something I didn't know worked in C++, but in my gcc compiler it works fine, so thank you for that, I still replaced it with `||` in my answer, though.

Apart from that there are some issues with the sequence of events in your `do - while` cycle, try the code below.

[**Live sample here**](https://onlinegdb.com/r1ji8RbB8)

```
do {
  if (a == 'y') {
    cout << "Processed all records successfuly" << endl;
    break;
  }
  if (a == 'n') {
    cout << "Enter number of records to process: ";
    cin >> ProcessAmount;

    if (ProcessAmount <= 0 || cin.fail()) {
      cout << "XXXXXXXXX Error-non numeric or negative value";
      cout << "" << endl;
    }
    else {
      cout << "Maximum requested record count of " << ProcessAmount;
      cout << " reached" << endl;
      break;
    }
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(40, '\n');
    continue;
  }

  cout << "Please try again" << endl;
  cout << "Would you like to process all the records in the file? "
       << "(y/n) ";
  cin >> a;

} while (a != 'y');
```

Comment: In my textbook I am using, they use both or and ||, is there a specific difference in using or and ||?

Comment: @HaikHakopyan I didn't know that it could still be used, but it works fine, I guess it's valid, by answering your question I learned something, I guess it's karma. :) BTW I changed the code a bit more removing some unnecessary lines that were doing redundant things.

Comment: `or` is valid since time immemorial, opposite is only stated by microsoft devs and those who ever used only their compiler

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, yes, I dind't know that, I already changed my answer.

Comment: @HaikHakopyan, I made some more changes to account for non y/n chars  in the first question, something it wasn't doing.

Comment: @anastaciu thank you for your help! was able to get that part of my assignment running.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the value of `a` must be validated, with something like:

```
cout << "Would you like to process all the records in the file? "
    << "(y/n) ";
cin >> a;
//validating a
while (a != 'n' && a != 'y'){
    cout << "Error - Please enter either y or n." << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to process all the records in the file? "
        << "(y/n) ";
    cin >> a;
} 

//...do things if a='n'

//...do thing if a='y'
```

then you should stop worrying about `a`, then you can do things if `a = n` or if `a = y`